# Flutter TabBar custom indicator

Tags: flutter, tabs, shadow, tabbarcontroller

To understand what I'm trying to achieve, look at the screenshot:
[image]

But as you can see, the tab's shadow can not fit inside the Tab.
So how do I make space for the shadow?

Here is how I build a Tab:

```
Tab buildTab(CategoryModel category) {
return Tab(child: ConstrainedBox(
  constraints: BoxConstraints(
    minWidth: 48,
  ),
  child: Container(
    //color: Colors.green,
    child: Text(category.name, textAlign: TextAlign.center,),
  ),
),);
```

}

And this is how I builde the TabBar:

```
return TabBar(
  indicator: BoxDecoration(
      color: Colors.blue,
      borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
        const Radius.circular(999.0),
      ),
      boxShadow: const [BoxShadow(color: Colors.blueAccent, blurRadius: 6.0)]
  ),
  unselectedLabelColor: Colors.blue,
  labelColor: Colors.white,
  isScrollable: true,
  tabs: tabs,
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there parent of tabbar code?
When I tested, it works well.

[image]

Comment: yes, it works well, but the top and bottom of each tab's shadow is not displayed, because there is not enough space for it. I would like to adjust it.

Comment: Try to add more tabs, so that that tabbar would scroll. And also, try to give the blurRadius a higher value, like 32, 48.